# I have some tests that work separately, but that get broken when excuting them together (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

As the title says, I'm doing a project for univerity where I have to create a number of tables, and using some procedures, add, update and remove values from them. Nothing too hard. I've made a package for each table with the tests (inserting correct values, incorrect values, updating...) so it's easy to see what is failing, and also, for eache package I have this script that launch all the tests.

As of right now, executing those scripts on their own works perfectly. Every test returns the correct value. However, I'm trying to do like a *master script* so I can launch all the tests from one sql page. And it doesn't work. There is no 'error code', but the values that I get aren't the ones I'm expecting.

I've make sure of creating some 'dummy values' so the references between tables don't get broken, which would be the obvious error. What am I missing here?

EDIT: As some of you have told me, 'not working' isn't a good way to descrube my problem. I was rushing and I didn't think of it. The problem here is that I have two tables which are referenced by the rest, and while inserting values on them works flawlessly, on the ones that reference those two with foreign keys, I can't insert any values. The only solution that works as of right now is reinserting values on the two 'important' tables before each test, but this way I'm updating two variables with the same values at least nine times in a row.

Comment: Well in unit testing, each test is independent of other tests.  Applying this to your current Oracle setup, you might consider using temporary tables.

Comment: If I got it right, maybe you should not COMMIT between two tests (if you do), but **ROLLBACK**. Because, if one test performs UPDATE, another one doesn't work with "original" values but updated ones, so it won't return what you expect. Rollback might fix that.

Comment: "not working"  is a really poor error description. What are you doing? What do you expect? What do you get?

Comment: As a wild guess, is there PL/SQL code in a SQL*Plus (or SQL\*Plus compatible) script, and is that code terminated with the `/` character required by SQL\*Plus? However, [It's Not Working](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) is not a great way to start diagnosing a problem.